# Redirigir a una url en href

Tags: python-3.x, django

Hice un codigo que permite redigirise a la pagina relacionada al *todos* cuando teclmos sobre el texto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`currenttodos.html`

```
<ul>
    {% for todo in todos %}
    <li>
        <a href="{% url 'viewtodo' todo.id %}">
        {% if todo.important %}<b>{% endif %}{{ todo.title }}{% if todo.important %}</b>{% endif %}
        {% if todo.memo %} -{{ todo.memo }}- {% endif %}
        </a>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Sin embargo no me redigiro a la buena url.

Deve me redirijir a `http://localhost:8000/todo/1`, pero me redirigirá a `http://127.0.0.1:8000/current/%7B%%20url%20'viewtodo'%201%20%7D`.

En efecto cuando hace un clic sobre uno de los vinculo, me devuelve:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/current/%7B%25%20url%20'viewtodo'%201%20%7D
Using the URLconf defined in todowoo.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
signup/ [name='signupuser']
logout/ [name='logoutuser']
login/ [name='loginuser']
[name='home']
current/ [name='currenttodos']
todo/<int:todo_pk> [name='viewtodo']
create/ [name='createtodo']
The current path, current/{% url 'viewtodo' 1 }, didn't match any of these.
```

## Otras partes del mio codigo

Aqui esta `urls.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from todo import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),

    # Auth
    #... 

    # Todos
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
    path('current/', views.currenttodos, name="currenttodos"),
    path('todo/<int:todo_pk>', views.viewtodo, name="viewtodo"),
    path('create/', views.createtodo, name="createtodo")
]
```

Y `viewtodo()` en `views.py`:

```
def viewtodo(request, todo_pk):
    # grab the todo from the primary key
    todo = get_object_or_404(Todo, pk=todo_pk)
    return render(request, 'todo/viewtodo.html', {'todo':todo})
```

Comment: necesitas redireccionar cuando haya hecho la llamada a la vista y luego que ejecute una función o directamente desde la vista ?

Comment: Esta muy raro, no si hiciste una configuración rara o algo así... intenta poner `{% url 'viewtodo' todo.id %}` a secas en el template, a ver que te sale...